# Inject with Ninject log4net in to property of custom FilterAttribute

Tags: c#, ninject, log4net

I created a custom LogFilterAttribute and I want to inject the ILog object into the Logger property. When I debug the project the property Logger of the ActionFilterAttribute is null.

```
public class LogFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or sets the value of the logger object
    /// </summary>
    public ILog Logger { get; internal set; }

    //some loggging with the Logger Property in the overriden methods
}
```

I register the injection in the NinjectWeCommon.cs in the method RegisterServices.

```
    kernel.Bind<LogFilterAttribute>().ToSelf().WithPropertyValue("Logger", LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global)));
```

When I'm attached to the debugger in the LogFilterAttribute the property Logger is null. How can I solve this issue?

(The configuration is set in the web.config)

greetings

Comment: Are you applying this as an attribute to controllers/actions or adding it to the global filter collection?

Comment: I apply this attribute on a webapi controller/action.

Comment: There appears to be [docs on this very subject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-filters): use [`BindFilter` rather than `Bind`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations).

Comment: The docu seems to be outdated. I'm using Ninject 3.2.0.0 and the compiler tells me there is no BindFilter method. I tried to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757419/using-ninject-to-bind-webapi-filter-attributes this. But at the moment I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: I think I remember reading that filters arent instanciated by the container. However they seem to support property injection by putting a `[Inject]` attribute on the property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839293/asp-net-mvc3-actionfilterattribute-injection

Comment: I think `BindFilter` comes from an additional MVC specific extension to the core NInject.