# Singleton Scope binding not working as intended

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-web-api

I am using the ninject mvc3 plugin with my web api application. I have a binding that looks like:

`kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();`

It is my interpretation that the kernal will create exactly one instance of `Foo` and reuse it appropriately. By putting a breakpoint in `Foo`'s constructor, I can clearly see that it is getting called once per request, and I cannot explain why.

My only guess is that somehow a new kernel is getting created per request, but that doesn't appear to be the case, as the `CreateKernel` method which sets the global dependency resolver is only getting run once in the application lifetime.

I am using some code taken from [this post](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/) to make ninject play nice with mvc 4. Because of framework changes, I had to make an additional wrapper that I assign to `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`:

```
public class NinjectResolver : NinjectScope, IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    public NinjectResolver(IKernel kernel)
        : base(kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }
    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return new NinjectScope(_kernel.BeginBlock());
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps not related to captncraig's issue, but relevant to the title. I had the same problem and it turned out I accidentally was injecting the implementation into one of my objects rather than the interface. So in the constructor I had accidentally put Foo instead of IFoo. Hope this helps someone out there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I never could get it to work properly, and I am not sure why. My guess is it has something to do with MVC4 integration being a bit immature at the moment.

As an alternative I am using:

`kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToConstant(new Foo());`

This seems to work, but I am not too happy with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356864/ninject-insingletonscope-with-web-api-rc

Answer (score 4):

Like previously mentioned it does look like a bug.
One option is to simply implement a singleton extension method yourself:

```csharp
public static class NinjectSingletonExtension
{
    public static CustomSingletonKernelModel<T> SingletonBind<T>(this IKernel i_KernelInstance)
    {
        return new CustomSingletonKernelModel<T>(i_KernelInstance);
    }
}

public class CustomSingletonKernelModel<T>
{
    private const string k_ConstantInjectionName = "Implementation";
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
private static object padlock = new Object();

    private T _concreteInstance;


    public CustomSingletonKernelModel(IKernel i_KernelInstance)
    {
        this._kernel = i_KernelInstance;
    }

    public IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> To<TImplement>(TImplement i_Constant = null) where TImplement : class, T
    {
        _kernel.Bind<T>().To<TImplement>().Named(k_ConstantInjectionName);
        var toReturn =
            _kernel.Bind<T>().ToMethod(x =>
                                       {
                                           if (i_Constant != null)
                                           {
                                               return i_Constant;
                                           }

                                           if (_concreteInstance == null)
                       {
                       lock (padlock)
                       {
                        if (_concreteInstance == null)
                        {
                            _concreteInstance = _kernel.Get<T>(k_ConstantInjectionName);
                        }
                           }
                       }


                                           return _concreteInstance;
                                       }).When(x => true);

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

And then simply use:

```
i_Kernel.SingletonBind<T>().To<TImplement>();
```

Rather then

```
i_Kernel.Bind<T>().To<TImplement>().InSingletonScope();
```

Answer (score 4):

Certainly arriving late to this thread but it just happened to me with a Windows Service hosting OWIN for Web API controllers and resolving dependencies with Ninject, InSingletonScope() wasn't working until I did the following:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
...
kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<Foo>());
...

// Controllers ask for the dependency as usual...
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    readonly IFoo _foo;

    public SomeController(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }
...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks it solve my issue, Also with WebAPI controllers, If somebody have a clear explanation why.. I'm interested in!

Answer (score 1):

Note: I used nuget to install ninject & ninject.web.mvc (which I'm sure you did as well).

I'm not able to see the rest of your code, but here's what I had in my "NinjectDependencyScope" class.  (I think yours is just called NinjectScope, might be some other naming inconsistencies with your code)

```
public class NinjectDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
{
    private IResolutionRoot _resolver;

    internal NinjectDependencyScope(IResolutionRoot resolver)
    {
        Contract.Assert(resolver != null);

        _resolver = resolver;
    }

    #region IDependencyScope Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var disposable = _resolver as IDisposable;
        if (disposable != null)
            disposable.Dispose();

        _resolver = null;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (_resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");
        return _resolver.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (_resolver == null)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed");

        return _resolver.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And here is my NinjectWebCommon class (located in App_Start folder):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Web.Common;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ABCD.Project.Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(ABCD.Project.Web.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace ABCD.Project.Web.App_Start
{
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper Bootstrap = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        Bootstrap.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        Bootstrap.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);

        // Set Web API Resolver
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        //var modules = new INinjectModule[] { new NinjectBindingModule(), };
        //kernel.Load(modules);
        Here's where you would load your modules or define your bindings manually...
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: My controller requires an `IBar` which takes an `IFoo` in the constructor.

Comment: Bear with me while I get back up to speed on my old MVC 4 web api app that used ninject...  your code sample looks somewhat familiar to what I had done...

Comment: I think maybe something odd is going on. Your code looks very similar to mine, except you are using `_resolver.TryGet` and I have been using `_resolver.Resolve`. The `TryGet` methods don't exist on my version of `IResolutionRoot`. Are you using the mvc3 plugin?

Comment: I am using the Ninject.Mvc extension.  From what I can see on my end, TryGet is an extension method to IResolutionRoot in Ninject DLL though.  What versions of these NuGet packages are you using?  I have Ninject 3.0.1.10, Ninject.Web.Common 3.0.0.7, and Ninject.MVC3 3.0.0.6

Comment: It looks like I had to add "using Ninject.Syntax" to get the TryGet extension method to work as well.

Comment: I have the same NinjectDependencyScope  as captncraig and I'm still getting the same issue, did you ever get this resolved properly?