# Items not in cache after adding it. using Web Api and Memory Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-web-api2, memorycache

When i add items to the Memory Cache, it is empty on the next request. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my cache service:

```
    public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache;

    public CacheService(ObjectCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public virtual void Add(object item, string key, int cacheTime, ExpirationInterval expirationInterval = ExpirationInterval.Hours)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;
        var cachePolicy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        switch (expirationInterval)
        {
            case ExpirationInterval.Minutes:
                cachePolicy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, cacheTime, 0);
                break;
            case ExpirationInterval.Hours:
                cachePolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddHours(cacheTime);
                break;
            case ExpirationInterval.Infinite:
                cachePolicy.AbsoluteExpiration = ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("expirationInterval");
        }
        _cache.Add(key, item, cachePolicy);
    }

    public bool Exists(string key)
    {
        return _cache[key] != null;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {

        return (T)_cache[key];
    }
```

Register my service with ninject here:

```
            kernel.Bind<System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache>()
            .To<System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache>()
            .InSingletonScope()
            .WithConstructorArgument("name", "Enquiries")
            .WithConstructorArgument("config", (object) null);
```

Then i use the cacheservice below in an enquiries service:

```
  public class EnquiriesService : IEnquiriesService
{
    private readonly ICacheService _cacheService;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public EnquiriesService(ICacheService cacheService, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _cacheService = cacheService;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Enquiry> GetEnquiries(DateTime date)
    {
        var cacheName = "Enquires_" + date.ToShortDateString();
        IEnumerable<Enquiry> enquiries;

        if (_cacheService.Exists(cacheName))
        {
            enquiries = _cacheService.Get<IEnumerable<Enquiry>>(cacheName);
        }
        else
        {
            enquiries =
                _unitOfWork.EnquiriesRepository.GetAll()
                    .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DateOfEnquiry) == date.Date);
            _cacheService.Add(enquiries, cacheName, 24);
        }
        return enquiries;
    }
```

this service is then injected into my controller:

```
        public EnquiriesController(IEnquiriesService enquiriesService)
    {
        _enquiriesService = enquiriesService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Enquiry> Enquiries(DateTime date)
    {
        return _enquiriesService.GetEnquiries(date);
    }
```

Any ideas why i can see then items added successfully but when i try to retrieve them 2nd time round there is nothing in the cache? I am assuming the memorycache is being instantiated on every request? How can i stop this, and allow my cache object to persist?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's buggy:

[Stackoverflow: Singleton Scope binding not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784447/singleton-scope-binding-not-working-as-intended) 
[Stackoverflow: Ninject InSingletonScope with Web Api RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356864/ninject-insingletonscope-with-web-api-rc?rq=1)

Both posts are old, but you seem encountering the same issues. Maybe you should use this approach instead:

```
kernel.Bind<System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache>()
        .To<System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache>()
        .ToConstant(new MemoryCache("Enquiries"));
```

or just

```
 kernel.Bind<System.Runtime.Caching.ObjectCache>()
        .To<System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache>()
        .ToConstant(MemoryCache.Default);
```