# Inject NServiceBus with Ninject in WebApi App

Tags: c#, ninject, nservicebus, asp.net-web-api

I´m trying to send a message to the queue from my WebApi application.
The first time the server starts everything goes fine and I can send a message to the queue from my controller, but the next time the action is called it throws the folloowing exception:

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'UnicastBus'.
```

This is how I´m binding the IBus interface

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon
{
    ...
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IBus>().ToConstant(CreateBus()).InSingletonScope();
    }

    private static IBus CreateBus()
    {
        Configure.Serialization.Xml();
        return Configure.With()
           .DefaultBuilder()
           .UseTransport<Msmq>()
           .UnicastBus()
           .SendOnly();
    }
}
```

And in my controller

```
public class CreatedOrderMessageController : ApiController
{
  private readonly IBus bus;

  public CreatedOrderMessageController(IBus bus)
  {
    this.bus = bus;
  }

  public string Get(int id)
  {
    bus.Send(new OrderCreatedMessage(id));
    return "true";
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on this error?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using the default builder for NSB (which is autofac) and then register it by constant? Try to use the extension method NinjectBuilder and pass in your kernel

Comment: Changed to use the NinjectBuilder, now I can send one message like before but on the second try it throws another error: Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

Comment: Did ypu reference the namedscope and the contextpreservation extension? This is required. Not referencing those will throw this obscure exception

Comment: No, I don´t know anything about this extensions, can you tell me more about?

Comment: Probably this modules are already been loaded, i try to put this this.kernel.Load(new NamedScopeModule());
this.kernel.Load(new ContextPreservationModule()); and the app throws that the modules are already been loaded

Comment: Got it this thread helps me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356864/ninject-insingletonscope-with-web-api-rc I was disposing the kernel and this generates issue with singleton scopes

Comment: Please create the answer below and accept it to help others, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed de code to use the NinjectBuilder

in the RegisterServices method I used:

```
Configure.Serialization.Xml();
      Configure.Transactions.Disable();
      Configure.With()
      .NinjectBuilder(kernel)
      .UseTransport<Msmq>()
      .UnicastBus()
      .SendOnly();
```

And this thread give me a tip [Ninject InSingletonScope with Web Api RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356864/ninject-insingletonscope-with-web-api-rc)

In order to Ninject work with WebApi I needed to implement a custom IDependencyScope I was disposing the kernel and I think it generated a issue with singleton scopes, so in Dispose method in IDependencyScope I do nothing